# How to get last PID when last process spawned a child and exited?

Tags: ssh, bash, pid

I start `ssh -S mysocket example.com` to connect `example.com`. If my connection hangs, I need to `kill` that process:

```
ssh -S mysocket example.com -N -L 1234:localhost:1234 &
last_pid=$!

...(do something blocker)

kill $last_pid
```

But that doesn't work. If `last_pid` is `XXXX`, when I check actual process with `ps -ef | grep ssh`, the process' pid seems `XXXX + 1`.

Which means that `ssh -S socket` starts in background, spawns a child and exit.

How do we capture last pid in this case?

Comment: `$!` is set when you put a command in the background using `&`. Since you aren't using `&` anywhere in your question I can't figure out what exactly you are expecting to happen.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to add `&` in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the `ssh` is spawning multiplexer process for `ControlMaster` if you use `-S` switch. There is no simple way how to ask for that PID directly the `ssh`, but assuming you are not spawning many processes, you can use the output of the `ps` to get the PID, for example

```
ps f | grep "ssh -S mysocket" | cut -d " " -f 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This command will give you the pid of the master:

```
ssh -S mysocket -O check example.com
```

You can also use:

```
pgrep --full --exact "ssh -S mysocket example.com -N -L 1234:localhost:1234"
```